# Java 16, execution in jar stops in middle of the method without exception

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, runtime

My application stops with execution in de middle of an method, for example a decrypt method (i have seen is also in other methods). In Netbeans (12.3) execution goes as espected. But when i executed the jar file (build in Netbeans) the problem occured.

For Example:

```
 private void doIt() {
     //log is my own logging class
     log.info("pass: " + decrypt("TKRVAAmZaBuB4vlXQP6aOA=="));
 }

public String decrypt(String strToDecrypt)  {
        try {
            log.info("decrypt()  " + strToDecrypt);
            byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
            log.info("iv: " + iv);
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            log.info("IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);");
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
            log.info("SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256);");
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.toCharArray(), SALT.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
            log.info(" KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.toCharArray(), SALT.getBytes(), 65536, 256);");
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            log.info("SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);");
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
            log.info("SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(),AES);");
            
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            log.info("Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING);");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
            log.info(" cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);");
            String s = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
            log.info("return" + s);
            return s;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO
            log.logException(StocktransmitterApp.class, e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Log after excecution in jar:

```
2021-09-05 08:56:22 INFO decrypt()  TKRVAAmZaBuB4vlXQP6aOA==
2021-09-05 08:56:22 INFO iv: [B@3abbfa04
2021-09-05 08:56:22 INFO IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
```

Other info

- Jar is build by Netbeans
- The jar is invoked by a Launch4j exe
- The appication is a modular application
- The JDK is update to the latest version: 16.0.2.7
- Execution is from a custom jre (build by jlink)

It seams that the jar is not stable

This is strange behavior. I don't know how to fix
Has anyone ideas or suggestions?

Comment: *`log.logException`* I know of no logging API with that method. *Which* API are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As the whole execution context is unclear:

Note that an `Exception` is not the only thing that can be thrown: There might be an `Error`, which you don't catch and that might go undetected.

Specifically as you say that execution works in different contexts: Missing classes typically cause (unrecoverable) errors. For a first check: Catch `Throwable` and see if that changes anything. In general, your handling of an exception is ok, and Errors should be caught on a higher level IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your replies!i have found the problem
First i have catched throwable (next time, i should this first).
An java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError with java.lang.SecurityException: Can't read cryptographic policy directory: unlimited was thrown

If i googled on that message i discovered that the conf (with the security settings) directory in my (custom) JRE is also necessary.